# Python appending variables to the list

Tags: python, list, append

Hello I can't seem to get this working i got a list

```
  a = [{'Name': 150,'number': 100},{'Name': 190, 'number': 200},{'Name': 190, 'number': 300}]
```

i need to append some variables but i keep getting errors

```
a.append ({'Name':  + Name + ',' + 'number'+ ':' + Number})
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Full code:

```
    a = [{'Name': 150,'number': 100},{'Name': 190, 'number': 200},{'Name': 190, 'number': 300}]
    Name = '150'
    number = '10'

    a.append ({'Name':  + Name + ',' + 'number'+ ':' + Number})


    def get_number(name):
           return lambda x: x['number'] if x['Name']==name else 0

    names = sorted(set(map(lambda x: x['Name'], a)))
    result = [{'Name':name,'number':sum(map(get_number(name), a))} for name in names]

    string = str(result)
    remove = "[{}],'"
    for i in range (0,len(remove)):
           string =string.replace(remove[i],"")
    b = string

    print b
```

How do i append the data to this list?

Comment: Why are you converting the list to a string and then use string operations to remove an item?!

Comment: Im converting to al list  because i'm getting names and numbers.  the sames names need to be added so i can see the total for the name and then add it to an xml element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to append a dictionary. This should work:

```
a.append({'Name': Name, 'number' :  Number})
```

The style of writing you employed employs some very cute intuition, but that's not how this works :) Dictionaries will automatically format themselves in the way the other ones are laid out, you just need to feed them the right keys and values.

The reason you got an error was because of the `:` you put in front. That tells Python you're using a dictionary - but immediately after that you put a `+`. Now Python looks to the right, sees a string, thinks "Okay, you're trying to add two strings to each other", looks to the left and sees a colon which is not a string. Python is confused: it needs something that can be interpreted as a string on the left, otherwise this isn't going to work. So it throws an error.

*Edit*: Correction about the unary operator, please see @PM 2Ring's comments!

Comment: "looks to the left and sees a colon which is not a string". No. The parser has already dealt with the colon and now it's looking for a valid expression to build a value from to associate with the `'Name'` key. It _doesn't_ try to interpret the `+` as a summing operator (which with strings means string concatenation), it interprets it as a [unary positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#Unary_negative_and_positive) operator (as the error message states), but that operator isn't defined for strings.

Comment: (cont) Unary positive _is_ defined for numbers, so we can do things like `a = +5` and `a = +b`, where `b` is a number. True, that's pretty useless, but it's symmetrical with  `a = -b`, and it's cheap to build handling unary positive into the parser. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `+` here: you can just put the variable value after the key, like you did when you first declared the value of `a`:

```
a.append ({'Name': Name, 'number': Number})
```

`+` is for joining strings or adding numbers, but here we're trying to create a dictionary. The format to do that is:

```
{"Key": value, "Another Key": value, ...}
```

The `+` signs aren't required because you aren't *joining* anything, you're just creating a dictionary using Python's built-in syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the error is evident and also the TypeError clearly tells you where the error is. You need not use the '+' in the statement. Simply edit the code to look as follows:

a.append ({'Name': Name, 'number': Number})

The '+' is used to append strings and in your case you are assigning a variable to a value. Hope it helps. :)